# FreeBSD shared swap partition with Linux

Tags: linux, freebsd, swap, shared-partition

What must I do, to run these commands before Arch Linux calls `swapon -a`?

```
mkswap /dev/sdaX
swapon /dev/sdaX
```

Just in case it matters, `/dev/sdaX` was created in FreeBSD 10.1 environment, as soon as FreeBSD doesn't care, Arch want to swap partition been exactly with certain headers.

Would be very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: why not simply add them in the relevant script just before `swapon`? :)

Comment: This is exactly what I thought about at first, but asking for more right-way solution. Nowadays I'm not using linux again, so question not actual. But still. Would be good if someone will answer.